# Count inner join

Tags: sql, join, count

** ANSWERED **

I am trying to output my albums in a repeater and show the amount of pictures that are in relation to the specific album. Allthough instead of showing all the albums and the amount of pictures, it multiple of the same album if more pictures are stored in it.

Here is my SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.gallery
AS
    SELECT 
     album.*, 
     COUNT(DISTINCT image.image_id) AS amount
    FROM album 
    INNER JOIN image
    ON image_FK_album = album.album_id 
    GROUP BY album.album_id, album.album_navn
    RETURN
```

Does any of you know what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*facepalm*
Shouldve known that i should be using left join